# How to create custom auditing entity listener that extends AuditingEntityListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, audit

I have implemented auditing through Sping Data JPA but now I want to be able to control the update and create timestamps with custom logic. So I want to write a custom auditing entity listener that extends the Auditingentitylistener.

I have the following generic entity class where I register the custom auditing entity listener:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
@EntityListeners(CustomAuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AuditableEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
    private Date created;

    @CreatedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_entity_created_by_id"))
    private Account createdBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_updated", nullable = false)
    private Date lastUpdated;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_updated_by_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_entity_last_updated_by_id"))
    private Account lastUpdatedBy;

    protected AuditableEntity() {
    }

    ...

}
```

The CustomAuditingEntityListener class is defined as

```
@Configurable
public class CustomAuditingEntityListener extends AuditingEntityListener {

    public CustomAuditingEntityListener() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    @PrePersist
    public void touchForCreate(Object target) {
        if (//custom logic) {
            super.touchForCreate(target);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @PreUpdate
    public void touchForUpdate(Object target) {
        if (//custom logic) {
            super.touchForUpdate(target);
        }
    }

}
```

The custom auditing entity listener is called correctly but when the `super.touchForCreate(target)` or `super.touchForUpdate(target)` gets called the timestamps are not set because the handler in the AuditingEntityListener class is null.

This is the code of the AuditingEntityListener class:

```
package org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support;

@Configurable
public class AuditingEntityListener implements ConfigurableObject {
    private ObjectFactory<AuditingHandler> handler;

    public AuditingEntityListener() {
        JoinPoint var2 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_1, this, this);
        JoinPoint var1 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, this, this);
        if (this != null && this.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Configurable.class) && AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.ajc$if$bb0((Configurable)this.getClass().getAnnotation(Configurable.class))) {
            AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf().ajc$before$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$1$e854fa65(this);
        }

        if ((this == null || !this.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Configurable.class) || !AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.ajc$if$bb0((Configurable)this.getClass().getAnnotation(Configurable.class))) && this != null && this.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Configurable.class) && AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$if$6f1(var1)) {
            AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf().ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(this);
        }

        if (!AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.ajc$if$bb0((Configurable)this.getClass().getAnnotation(Configurable.class)) && AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$if$6f1(var2)) {
            AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf().ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(this);
        }

    }

    public void setAuditingHandler(ObjectFactory<AuditingHandler> auditingHandler) {
        Assert.notNull(auditingHandler, "AuditingHandler must not be null!");
        this.handler = auditingHandler;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void touchForCreate(Object target) {
        if (this.handler != null) {
            ((AuditingHandler)this.handler.getObject()).markCreated(target);
        }

    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void touchForUpdate(Object target) {
        if (this.handler != null) {
            ((AuditingHandler)this.handler.getObject()).markModified(target);
        }

    }

    static {
        ajc$preClinit();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain how I can ensure that the AuditingHandler is not null and is set like it happens for the default AuditingEntityListener class?

Comment: `AuditingEntityListener` works in an odd way. Independent of what class is declared in `@EntityListeners`, `AuditingEntityListener` is instantiated and `setAuditingHandler()` is called. When `CustomAuditingEntityListener.touchForCreate()` is called, its `handler` is `null` because it is a different object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Spring 5.1 there is a rather straightforward way to autowire Spring components in the custom entity listener, so that the `AuditingHandler` can be used.

**1.** Declare the customer entity listener as a Spring component. Use constructor injection.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuditingEntityListener {

    private ObjectFactory<AuditingHandler> handler; 
    
    public CustomAuditingEntityListener(ObjectFactory<AuditingHandler> auditingHandler) {
        this.handler = auditingHandler;
    }

    @Override
    @PrePersist
    public void touchForCreate(Object target) {
        if (//custom logic) {
            AuditingHandler object = handler.getObject();
            if (object != null) {
                object.markCreated(target);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    @PreUpdate
    public void touchForUpdate(Object target) {
        if (//custom logic) {
            AuditingHandler object = handler.getObject();
            if (object != null) {
                object.markModified(target);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**2.** Tell Hibernate to use Spring as the bean provider by setting the appropriate configuration property:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig extends JpaBaseConfiguration {
    
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    protected JpaConfig(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties,
            ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManager) {
        super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        // This is the important line
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, new SpringBeanContainer(beanFactory));

        return properties;
    }
}
```

**--Edit-- Variation of 2.** Alternatively the [SpringBeanContainer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer.html) can be configured this way, with the benefit of not losing the Hibernate properties that Spring Boot populates:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {

        return builder.dataSource(dataSource) //
                .packages(BaseEntity.class) //
                .persistenceUnit("myunit") //
                .properties(Map.of(AvailableSettings.BEAN_CONTAINER, new SpringBeanContainer(beanFactory))) //
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Markus Pscheidt, the last solution worked for me. I have a multi-data-source Spring boot application and use `AuditingEntityListener` but all the class fields were null without the above configurations. I wonder why this happened.

Comment: @FaramarzAfzali The configuration is what makes the initialization of the fields possible, it connects Spring to the respective part of Hibernate.